# How to calculate prodcut of neurons(w1x1*w2x2*w3x3) instead of addition of neurons(w1x1+w2x2+w3x3) using keras

Tags: keras, deep-learning

```
model = Sequential()
Layer1 = Dense(12, input_dim=15, activation='relu')
model.add(Layer1)
Layer2 = Dense(1,kernel_constraint=unit_norm(), trainable=False)
model.add(Layer2)
```

I want to create visible layer consisting of 15 neurons and those are passed to hidden layer which are trainable weights and then passed to next layer which is having fixed weights(1) and those output were calculated as ((x1*1)(x2*1)(x3*1))

can any one please help me in this regard[image]

Comment: If I understood correctly, layer1 corresponds to x1, x2, x3, and layer2 to your fixed weights, right?

Comment: Yes and we need layer 2 input as (x1*fixed weight)*(x2*fixed weight)*(x3*fixed weight)

Comment: @chris Tosh added picture for your reference